# Why are prepared statements kept at a connection level by the JDBC drivers?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am not trying to ask what exactly they do, but rather why are they implemented the way they are. If prepared statements were handled completely by the Database, wouldn't it be available to all the connections? But it seems like most of it is handled by the Drivers against a connection, and I am not able to understand the reasoning behind that.

Asking with respect to Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a statement is prepared, it is sent to the database, which parses and analyzes the statement and sends back some kind of handle (=id) that can later be used to execute the statement as often as necessary. So instead of sending the entire statement to the database over and over again, just the handle and probably query parameters are transfered to the database.

As you already found out, prepared statements are bound to the current database connection, so when the connection is closed, the statement is removed from the database cache.

I have no idea how you think making such prepared statements public to all connections would have any benefit. If you really want to have public statements that are stored on the server, use [stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) or [SQL views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) instead!

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the returned handle part of it.
I was thinking, if it is sending some hash/complete sql query, then the query compilation/planning part could be skipped irrespective of the connection it come from. Thoughts?

Comment: OK, that's what you had in mind. Some kind of caching of optimizations in case another connection already has sent the same statement before. I don't know if databases (like Postgres) already do that (internally), but it is nothing you can control with prepared statements. Different story.

Comment: It is my understanding that some jdbc connection pools can do advanced handling of prepared statements. The connection you get from the pool does not relate directly to a raw jdbc connection. They can direct already, prepared statements to cached connections etc.

Comment: Minor point: postgres never _sends back some kind of handle_. A client sends `PREPARE name-of-statement AS query-for-statement` or the equivalent at the protocol level and PostgreSQL replies with success or error. The responsibility to come up with names that are unique within the connection is on the client.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why a prepared statement is bound to a connection (from the perspective of JDBC **and** from the database), and they boil down to "simplicity":

1. Resource management: by associating the statement with the connection, it is easy to cleanup any statements that haven't been explicitly closed: if the connection closes, so will any open statements.
2. In most database systems, the statement handle is also the cursor handle, meaning that it can only be used by one connection at a time, having it bound to a connection then makes more sense.
3. The statement lifetime (or at least the execute lifetime, see 2) is associated with a transaction, which is also bound to a connection. Some database allow multiple active transactions on a connection, but JDBC assumes one per connection.
4. In most database systems, the prepare of a statement depends on the metadata (DDL) visibility of the transaction that prepared it, having a global pool would complicate this (eg which connection is allowed to use/see which statement).
5. User rights and privileges are sometimes - partially - checked at prepare time. A global pool would complicate this (see 4).

There are probably some other reasons that I forget right now. I think the most important one is the first (the others would be implemented differently if there was a global pool).

This doesn't stop databases systems from also having a global pool of prepared statements (or at least: the prepare metadata like the access paths, execution plan, etc). However from the perspective of the user an instance of a prepared statement is still bound to a connection.